# Is there a way to make 'go back" button redirect to another web page instead of redirecting to the previous page?

Tags: javascript

And can the same thing be done with 'refresh' button? I'm asking because I created a page that displays items the user saved to his list and these can be removed by clicking remove button. Once that happens the page refreshes (becasue the item gets deleted from mysql database) and when you click 'go back' the browser goes to the previous page that had the item, and that to me is a problem. The only solution I can think of is to redirect 'go back' to another page, specifically the page the user has come from.

Plz help me in showing me how to redirect to another page upon clicking 'go back'.

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this with [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API/Working_with_the_History_API).

From your description, user's history goes like:

`/foo -> /bar -- remove item --> /bar#refreshed`

Now you want user to go back to `/foo` upon clicking "go back" button, so:

`/foo <-- go back -- /bar#refreshed`.

The optimal solution IMO is that you **should not** refresh the `/bar` page. Instead use ajax to update part of the page that contains the data. And if address bar needs to be updated, you can use

```
history.replaceState({}, '', '/bar#refreshed)
```

This way only the address bar's content is changed, but no real page navigation/refresh is triggered, thus your user's histroy becomes `/foo -> /bar#refreshed`, cus you've **replaced** `/bar` with `/bar#refreshed`. And when user hits "go back" button, they just goes back to `/foo`.

---

A sub-optimal solution, if you cannot update just part of the page and must reload the `/bar` page, would be like following.

Before you refresh the page, you call:

```
history.replaceState({}, '', '/foo')
```

so that your user's history becomes:

```
[before] /foo -> /bar -- remove item --> /bar#refreshed
                   |
                   | # /bar is replaced by /foo
                   V 
[after]  /foo -> /foo -- remove item --> /bar#refreshed
```

This way when user hits "go back" they still goes back to `/foo`. Although the history contains an extra `/foo` node, but still gets the job done.